# My bootstrap grid system not working

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, grid-system

I had problem to apply my bootstrap gird system into the web-page. The bootstrap I applied is bootstrap 3.3.5, downloaded it from the [getbootstrap.com](http://getbootstrap.com/). And I had all the config things done, here is my project files directory:

[image: file directory]

And here is my index.html structure:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>My bootstrap</title>

    <meta charset="utf-8”>
    <meta name="viewport” content="width=‘device-width’,inital-scale=1.0”>

    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css” rel="stylesheet”>
    <link href="css/custom.css” rel="stylesheet”>

    <script src="/js/respond.min.js”></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <p>text</p>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <p>text</p>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <p>text</p>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <p>text</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

However the grid system not working when the browser size changed, it's  always stay the original style as the 4 divs layout in vertical. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, finally I found it's the punctuation that cause the problem! I should be more careful, and there're many things we should pay attention to it,like :

① The **order** of the **jquery** and the **bootstrap css** script to state.

② You should know a row is equal 12 columns,so don't abuse you row class.

③ Sometimes you should check you **chrome** **extenssions** ,it's maybe prohibit you load your local **.js** file.

④ Anyway more careful more better.

Comment: This pretty much gives the same answer I would've given. Except for the second part with the rows. Sure, one row is equal to 12 columns but it causes no problem what so ever if you use it the way that is used in the question. As long as in each viewport you have 12 column value and if it exceeds, make sure the dropping columns do that as well.